# Getting 404 error on query with NodeJS Express Router on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am getting a 404 error when I try and query /api/memories/testQuery in the browser. I get the console.log saying "in routes js" just fine in the log, however. I don't know why this doesn't work on Heroku: it works fine on my machine.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
module.exports = app => {
    console.log("in routes.js")
    const controller = require("../controllers/controller.js");
    var router = require("express").Router();

    
    // Create a new Tutorial
    router.post("/addUser", controller.addUser);
    // Retrieve all Tutorials
    router.post("/getAllMemoriesOfOneUser", controller.getAllMemoriesOfOneUser);
    // Retrieve all published Tutorials
    
    // Retrieve a single Tutorial with id
    router.post("/validateUser", controller.validateUser);

    router.post("/getAllUsers", controller.getAllUsers);

    router.post("/testQuery", (req, res) => {
      console.log("got into test query")
      res.json({ message: "Welcome to Memories application2." });
    })

    router.post("/deleteAllUsers", controller.deleteAllUsers);

    router.post("/deleteAllMemories", controller.deleteAllMemories);


    app.use('/api/memories', router);
  };
```

Comment: Which EXACT line of code causes the error and is "app.router() is not a function", the EXACT error message you're getting.  I don't see any `app.router()` in your code so it's a bit hard to see which line of code causes  the error.

Comment: You have two separate `app` variables in this code which seems like a possible source of problem.  The first comes from `const app = express();`.  The second is meant to be passed to the function you're exporting: `module.exports = app => { ...}`.  You shouldn't have two different `app` objects for one server so you're probably doing something wrong with at least one of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `"in routes.js"` log and not getting `"got into test query"`, most probably you trying to send the request with a different method. Make sure you are trying with POST method in both environments.